# dataframe: conditional replacement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with malicious URLs, where column **url_type** has static value **2**

```
    url_type    url_type_txt
    2           phishing/fraud
    2           trojan
    2           trojan
    2           phishing
```

I need to replace 2 to 1 in the column `url_type`, where `url_type_txt` has word **%phish%** (it can be "phishing", "phishing url" etc).
I tried to that in `for` loop and with `loc` like:

```
df3.loc[df3.url_type_txt=="phish", "url_type"] = 1
```

but it is not appropriate solution.

Could somebody help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) (to make sure you catch `Phish` as well as `phish`) and [`str.contains()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df.loc[df.url_type_txt.str.lower().str.contains('phish'), 'url_type'] = 1

>>> df3
   url_type    url_type_txt
0         1  phishing/fraud
1         2          trojan
2         2          trojan
3         1        phishing
```

Answer (score 1):

when working with strings regular list comprehension might be faster compared to vectorized Pandas methods:

```
In [5]: df.loc[['phish' in u for u in df.url_type_txt], 'url_type'] = 1

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   url_type    url_type_txt
0         1  phishing/fraud
1         2          trojan
2         2          trojan
3         1        phishing
```

Timing for 40.000 rows DF:

```
In [7]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [8]: df.shape
Out[8]: (40000, 2)

In [9]: %timeit df.loc[df.url_type_txt.str.lower().str.contains('phish'), 'url_type']
103 ms ± 875 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit df.loc[['phish' in u for u in df.url_type_txt], 'url_type']
10.7 ms ± 15.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [11]: %timeit df.loc[['phish' in u.lower() for u in df.url_type_txt], 'url_type']
19.3 ms ± 48.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [12]: %timeit df.loc[['phish' in u for u in df.url_type_txt.str.lower()], 'url_type']
41.1 ms ± 123 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: That's interesting... I'm always a bit disappointed when loops are more efficient than vectorized methods :(

Comment: @sacul, yeah, strings is a special case, so i'm always trying to compare vectorized methods to list comprehension when working with strings in Pandas/Numpy...